# How to replace deprecated KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds?

Tags: android, security, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

From android 11 setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds are deprecated in favor of setUserAuthenticationParameters inside KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder but seams there is any support for previous versions.

so, what are best the solution ?

```
KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(...)
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    builder.setUserAuthenticationParameters(timeout, KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL | KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG);
else
    //noinspection deprecation
    builder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(timeout);
```

this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to migrate the actual keys, when you are ready to support Android 11 you can just switch to something like this, (don't forget to set `compileSdkVersion 30` for the new APIs)

```kotlin
val timeout = 30 //seconds
val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(...)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    builder.setUserAuthenticationParameters(timeout, 
       KeyProperties.AUTH_DEVICE_CREDENTIAL 
         or KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG
    )
} else {
    builder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(timeout)
}
```

You can do this because internally `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` is doing the same thing. The only exception is if you are calling `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds` with `-1` as the timeout. In this case the equivalent with the new API is `builder.setUserAuthenticationParameters(0, KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG)`.

You can check [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r3:frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.java;l=1236-1246;drc=a811787a9642e6a9e563f2b7dfb15b5ae27ebe98) the source code for both cases.

> PS: The code above is minAPI 24, you need to wrap the code above in more build checks if you are at a lower API level.

Comment: thanks i don't know why even if minsdk is lower than 30 we not receive any warning by android studio abount lev 30 required. i receive much "method not found" crash in prodution :(